# PInvokeStackImbalance when calling "DLL"(generated by Fortran) in VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, dll, fortran, fortran90

I am trying to call DLL in VB.NET 2010,which is generated by Fortran 90(the compiler is Intel Parallel Studio XE 2011). However,the "PInvokeStackImbalance" occurs when I run it.
I have tried the methods below: 
(1)Change the data tye in the declaration,such as "INTEGER","LONG","INT32"... ,but the error still exits. 
(2)Check the dimension of array in actual&virtual parameter.As there is no array when transporting,this method is ignored. 
(3) Uncheck the options for "ContextSwitchDeadlock" and "PInvokeStackImbalance" in "Debug - Exceptions - Managed Debugging Assistants".I think it can't solve the real problem,so I don't use it.

I notice that the error occurs in different circulation(see figure below,occur in 98 and 99,respectively).Does that mean the DLL itself have some error instead of the interface?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHKBB.png) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6DXc.png)

Below is my code in VB.net and the declaration in Fortan.
(1)VB.net:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Declare Sub main_sub Lib "smgama_dll.dll" (ByRef cla As Long, ByRef nf As Long)
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cla, nf As Long
        cla = CLng(TextBox1.Text)
        nf = CLng(TextBox2.Text)
        Call main_sub(cla, nf)
    End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
End Class
```

(2)Fortran:

```
subroutine main_sub(cla,nf)
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::main_sub
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:"main_sub"::main_sub

  use Global
  use suba
  use suba1
  use suba2

  implicit none
  real,allocatable::upbound(:),downbound(:),xbest(:),y(:),ybest(:),upbound1(:),downbound1(:),g_x(:),g_y(:)
  real,allocatable::QC(:),QCC(:),Q_mean(:)
  character(len=20)::filename
  integer::n,szz,tt,nf,i,iter,cla,j
......
End subroutine
```

Comment: For future reference, when you provide a link to an image and the prompt "enter image description here" is displayed, actually enter the image description.

Comment: This is a VB6 declaration.  In VB.NET "integer" = Integer, not Long.

Answer (score 0):

A stack imbalance almost always results from using a VB6 declaration in VB.NET.  Most API functions work with 32-bit numbers, which means `Long` in VB6 and `Integer` in VB.NET.  If you're using `Long`, which you are, then you're almost certainly using VB6 declarations.  Change the `Long` types to `Integer` at least and it may work, or you may need some other changes too.